# How to rotate a box div while dragging an element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand that we need to use `transform: rotate(ndeg);` in order to rotate a specific element in CSS. In this case, I want to do it dynamically. Using jQuery, I want to rotate the box/container div when the user **drags** the handle *(the red background)* on ***n*** degrees as the user wishes. Is it possible in jQuery?

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.box_element {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.handle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box_element">
    THIS IS TEST
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you need to write few code to make it possible, try live code https://codepen.io/libin-prasanth/pen/xxxzbLg

```js
var stop,
  active = false,
  angle = 0,
  rotation = 0,
  startAngle = 0,
  center = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  R2D = 180 / Math.PI;

function start(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var bb = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
    t = bb.top,
    l = bb.left,
    h = bb.height,
    w = bb.width,
    x,
    y;
  center = {
    x: l + w / 2,
    y: t + h / 2
  };
  x = e.clientX - center.x;
  y = e.clientY - center.y;
  startAngle = R2D * Math.atan2(y, x);
  return (active = true);
}

function rotate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = e.clientX - center.x,
    y = e.clientY - center.y,
    d = R2D * Math.atan2(y, x);
  rotation = d - startAngle;
  return (rot.style.webkitTransform = "rotate(" + (angle + rotation) + "deg)");
}

function stop() {
  angle += rotation;
  return (active = false);
}

rot = document.getElementById("draggable");
rot.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  if (active === true) {
    event.preventDefault();
    rotate(event);
  }
});
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  stop(event);
});
```

```css
#draggable { 
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px; 
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid #000;
} 
#draggable:before{
  content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -5px;
 right: -5px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a [css-variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and then change the value of the variable when clicked.

```js
const box_element = document.getElementById('box_element');
const handle = document.getElementById('handle');

handle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let currentVal = getComputedStyle(box_element).getPropertyValue('--rotate_deg');

  box_element.style.setProperty(
    '--rotate_deg', ((parseInt(currentVal.replace('deg', '')) + 90) % 360) + 'deg');

});
```

```css
:root {
  --rotate_deg: 0deg;
}

.box_element {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: rotate(var(--rotate_deg))
}

.handle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_element" id="box_element">
  THIS IS TEST
  <div class="handle" id="handle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this solution is only for click event. But how about if the red is `dragged`? The box should rotate while the red is dragged `n` degree.

Comment: you need to make the necessary calculation for the `n` in the drag event. The OP here is to dynamically change the `n`

Comment: The click event is okay. But how about the `drag` event? The user should click the `red` element while *holding the mouse*, then drag on `n` degree.

Comment: I guess that should be a different question, how to drag with another div and rotate. The post here was how to change the angle directly. You need to make sure OP is specific to one issue rather than multiple.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is only one question. **The main problem is how to rotate the main box on `n` degree**. Of course, you cannot rotate without clicking and dragging. You cannot drag without clicking. So the user should click first, then drag. I hope it sounds clear.

Comment: yep, i do understand your issues. But, you have *how to drag* and *how to rotate* as one question. I suggest, you ask the first question as a different post. For the second question, i guess the above has answered it. Thanks

Comment: mate, this is not the way you should be asking. People take time and effort to answer and once answered the main problem, you are editing the question to a different problem.